# Load id of paragraph in hook_preprocess_layout using load($id) method

Tags: theming, 8

I want to load the paragraph id in theme preprocess.

```
function theme_preprocess_layout(&$variables) {
  $ID = $variables['content']['#paragraph'] ???; "contents - protected 'id' => array(1) = 68"
  $variables['attributes'] = new Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute($variables['attributes']);
  $variables['attributes']->addClass($ID);}
```

It gives me the available method "load($id)" but I don't know how to implement this method.

Comment: All entities support the `id()` method. So, try $`variables['content']['#paragraph']->id();`. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/class/Entity/8.7.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Beau for the help.
The method is simply

`$ID = $variables['content']['#paragraph']->id();`